# Decode a gamma encoded image

Tags: image, decode, gamma, gamma-function

I am working on a project, where the user can specify a gamma function on a image, for example:

```
y=(pow(10,(1023*x-681)/444)-.0408)/(1-.0408))
```

The image is then encoded with this gamma curve, and then my code must be able to return this image back to its original (linear) version:

```
(y=x)
```

My question is how I can decode a gamma corrected image back to a linear version if i know the encoding function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inverse function

```
x = (444 * (log ((1-.0408) * y + .0408) / log 10) + 681) / 1023
```

Comment: The only problem is that the user can enter any function they like. So i can't specify the inverse function ahead.

Comment: Then solve the equation numerically or symbolically (matlab, mathematica, octave, ...)